# why are boolean attributes saved as null even when assigned default mysql values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

This must be a straightforward error but i cannot pinpoint why its happening.  I have changed my post from an earlier question which I did not really post accurately from my project.  Here is a better post for those of you who might have seen the previous one.  Essentially, I have two boolean values, `:accepted`, and `:complete`.  I have assigned default `:accepted => true`, and `:complete => false`, but still they save as null when I create a new `:accept` object.  Files:

accepts_controller.rb (create, and params)

```
def create
  @self_delivery = SelfDelivery.find_by(
    id: params[:self_delivery_id])

  begin
    @accept = Accept.create(
      :user_id => current_user.id,
      :self_delivery_id => @self_delivery.id,
      :accepted => params[:accepted],
      :complete => params[:complete])

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
    flash[:notice]= 'Duplicate Record'
  end

  if @accept.save!
    redirect_to accept_path(@accept)
    flash[:notice]= 'Accept was successfully created.'
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New Accept</h1>

<%= form_with(model: @accept, url: self_delivery_accepts_path(:user_id => params[:user_id], :self_delivery_id => params[:self_delivery_id]), :method => :post) do |form| %>
<% if @accept.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@accept.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this accept from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @accept.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= form.label :accepted %>
<%= form.check_box :accepted, checked: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
<%= form.label :complete %>
<%= form.check_box :complete, checked: true %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= form.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Back', self_delivery_accepts_path(:self_delivery_id => params[:self_delivery_id], :accepted => params[:accepted], :complete => params[:complete]) %>
```

puts params.inspect

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ANOwCS3enYdqqcN01iAJg7EgRDhAC/Gpb3/h6yCGz2qSrKEz874ANBYeKGQuKSc3ctopIixI4rKiKuC5FJdsnQ==", "accept"=>{"accepted"=>"1", "complete"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Accept", "controller"=>"accepts", "action"=>"create", "self_delivery_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: Add a line `puts params.inspect` in the very beginning of your `create` method and check what `params` come from the frontend.

Comment: added in edits, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what comes as params from your frontend:

```
..., "accept"=>{"accepted"=>"1", "complete"=>"0"}, ...
```

meaning in your code you should respect this format:

```
:accepted => params['accept']['accepted'],
:complete => params['accept']['complete']
```

Comment: Hey man, thaaaankyou.  It wasn't clear to me that the parameters needed 'accept' to specify parameters. Really now its clear.  You are a shining star!